# How can a npm package ever possibly affect the beforeLaunch stage of the execution for Protractor?

Tags: node.js, npm, jasmine, protractor, jasmine-reporters

While looking through the code in the protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter npm package I noticed that it contains a beforeLaunch function, which is exported with the rest of the functions.

I know that the lifecycle stages run in the following order so my question is:
How can this reporter ever possibly affect the beforeLaunch stage of the execution when the jasmine object itself isn't available until the onPrepare stage?

```
--- beforeLaunch           
    --- onPrepare          (set in conf) ***reporters initialized here
      --- jasmineStarted   (set in reporter)
        --- beforeAll
         --- suiteStarted  (set in reporter)
          --- specStarted  (set in reporter)
           --- beforeEach  (set in testFile)
           +++ afterEach   (set in testFile)
          +++ specDone     (set in reporter)
         +++ suiteDone     (set in reporter)
        +++ afterAll
      +++ jasmineDone      (set in reporter)
    +++ onComplete         (set in conf)
+++ afterLaunch
```

**Code from protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter**

```
function Jasmine2ScreenShotReporter(opts) {

  this.beforeLaunch = function (callback) {
  };

  this.afterLaunch = function (callback) {
  };

  this.jasmineStarted = function (suiteInfo) {
  };

  this.suiteStarted = function (suite) {
  };

  this.suiteDone = function (suite) {
  };

  this.specStarted = function (spec) {
  };

  this.specDone = function (spec) {
  };

  this.jasmineDone = function () {
  };

  return this;
}
```

I possible I have fundamentally misunderstood some behavior here but hope someone can shed some light on this for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protractor uses extra plugin hooks and resolves these in addition to the Jasmine hooks. These are usually resolved in Protractor's runner. You can read up on the plugins here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/plugins.ts#L25

So for example, `onPrepare` plugin is checked in the config (https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/selenium4/lib/runner.ts#L63) and executed by the runner (https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/selenium4/lib/runner.ts#L82). These two files referencing the runner is for the selenium 4 upgrade branch. It is easier to look at these versions since they do not have a chain of thenable promises.

Comment: Thanks for this info @cnishina it was helpful to read. I am having trouble understanding though why only onPrepare is listed in the plugin file. What makes it unique compared to beforeLaunch, afterLaunch or onComplete?

Comment: These are all plugin hooks. They just happen at different points in Protractor's runner.

Comment: Good to know. So to take this back the to the original question, if all these plugin hooks occur during different stages of the runner then I take it an npm package imported during the onPrepare stage can not affect any stages prior to it such as the beforeLaunch? If so then could you tell me what is the purpose of having the beforeLaunch in protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter example I've pasted above?

Comment: Yes, if your `onPrepare` method occurs after the `beforeLaunch` (in the order provided above), any package added in `onPrepare` will not affect the `beforeLaunch`. I have seen a lot of reporters added into the onPrepare method and would suggest doing it there. Also I haven't looked into it recently on the lifecycle hooks since I did not work on that feature. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks cnishina, so my final question before I accept this answer is why would a package like protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter ever export a beforeLaunch function if it can never be called prior to the beforeLaunch stage. Do you know is this likely a mistake from the package creators side or is it just that it is useful while building the function?

Comment: This is something the developer of this repo wanted. So he defined the `beforeLaunch` method to create the report destination (see https://github.com/mlison/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter/blob/master/index.js#L478). I would follow the tutorial on adding it in. https://github.com/mlison/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter. It is interesting that he requires to resolve the promise in the `beforeLaunch` method but nothing in the `beforeLaunch` leads me to believe it is async.

Comment: Ah I think I finally get it! He recommends manually activating the reporters beforeLaunch function during your projects actual beforeLaunch function. I am assuming this is because you are unable to actually activate the reporter until the onPrepare stage as the Jasmine global variable has not been configured. I may still be slightly misunderstanding but this has answered my initial question. Thanks very much.